# I can't resolve the Button class in Android Studio when I tried to call it. Alt+Enter or Ctrl+Space doesn't resolve it. Any ideas?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have designed the UI for my application with all the elements that needed in this application, include button. But when I want to call the Button class in MainActivity, it can't call the class and import it, Alt+Enter & Ctrl+Space didn't help. When I press Ctrl+Space doesn't show the Button class but shows **ButtonBarLayout** instead. Any idea where is the error?

Comment: `Any idea where is the error?` Yeah, an error is in your code. How can I check where is an error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for help. I have already solved the problem. It is the class package of Button that have been excluded from the **auto-import**. So it doesn't show the auto-import like this [Button Class auto-import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLFp1.png) but shows up only the ButtonBarLayout

I'm sorry for my question that has not been clear enough.